# Can I tell selenium to operate in tabs without switching to them?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, browser-tab

Let me start by saying that this is my first post to stackoverflow, so please tell me when I did something wrong.

I did a project where I open a firefox, create multiple tabs and then go to different websites in each of them, startin from left to right. At the moment, every time the work in one tab is done, it switches to the next one and starts working there. However, what my customer wants the browser to do is that it stays on the first tab opened, so that he can look at the results displayed, while selenium continues to work in the other tabs in the background.

I open the new tabs with

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get((tabPosition)));
```

To be honest, I don't even know if this is possible at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on `it stays on the first tab opened, so that he can look at the results displayed, while selenium continues to work in the other tabs in the background`

Comment: Basically what I wanted to say is that the work done by selenium should run in the background, so that the customer is able to view at the stuff displayed in the first (or any other) tab while selenium does his work in the other tabs without actively switching to them. Sorry if I can't express myself well enough, english is not my first language.

Comment: Okay, Do you want that Selenium would do its own work (Automation Testing) & the customer will do his/her own work (browsing different sites). The customer is interested only at the End Result whether testcases are Pass/Fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clear answer is NO

Selenium required focus to correspondent window/tab/frame to work on and interact with the element of that page.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @NarendraRajput Free doughnut for you :) I was thinking headless

Answer (score 0):

Yours customer's wishes incorrect. Driver work in background.
You have to return to your first tab after Selenium go to enother tab. For this add to your code string:

```
String firstTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

And after any tabs always switch your driver to the first tab:

```
for (String tab: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!tab.equals(firstTab)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(firstTab);
    }
}
```